# Why doesn't my checkout flow work?

Tags: commerce

I am working on a site that integrates with our company's ordering and payment system. I have a flow I need to create that, after the customer clicks the checkout button, it takes them to a login/register page, then to a place to enter their shipping and billing address, then to a shipping page (which our service provides the shipping costs), then to a payment page. I created a custom flow called 'SRSCheckoutFlow' and here is my code:

```
class SRSCheckoutFlow extends CheckoutFlowWithPanesBase {

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getSteps() {
      return [
          'login' => [
            'label' => $this->t('Login'),
            'previous_label' => $this->t('Return to cart'),
            'has_order_summary' => FALSE,
          ],
          'order' => [
            'label' => $this->t('Order Information'),
            'previous_label' => $this->t('Return to login'),
            'has_order_summary' => FALSE,
          ],
          'shipping' => [
            'label' => $this->t('Shipping Service'),
            'previous_label' => $this->t('Return to order information'),
            'has_order_summary' => FALSE,
          ],
          'review' => [
            'label' => $this->t('Review'),
            'has_order_summary' => TRUE,
          ],
          'payment' => [
            'label' => $this->t('Payment'),
            'has_order_summary' => TRUE,
          ],
          'payment_processing' => [
            'label' => $this->t('Payment Processing'),
            'has_order_summary' => TRUE,
          ],
        ] + parent::getSteps();
    }

  }
```

Problems are when I am not logged in, I go to the login/register page as desired but after I register, I get sent to a blank Checkout page. If I am already logged it, I get sent to the shipping page which misses the part where I need the user to add their shipping and billing information.

In Home > Administration > Commerce > Configuration > Checkout flows, I have all the steps created in the SRSCheckoutFlow and I added the following to each step

Login

- Login or continue as guest

Order Information

- Shipping information
- Contact information

Shipping Service

- Shipping Services (which is custom and showing correctly)

Review

- Review

Payment

- Payment information

[image: Workflow Layout]

Am I missing something in the flow that jumps over the *Shipping information* and *Contact information* sections?

Comment: Check your order types `/admin/commerce/config/order-types`. If you didn't create any, edit default, scroll all the way down. Make sure your checkout flow is set to your `SRSCheckoutFlow`

Comment: Thanks No Sssweat! I checked the order-types and have the SRSCheckoutFlow selected, I also have workflow set to fulfillment since items will be shipped. When I add items to the cart, then click checkout, I have login or register (which is correct), then it takes me to a Order Information page which shows the order but no shipping or billing information and no button to go to the next step.

Comment: Ok, I figured out the shipping information was showing due to my variation type reverting to not shippable. However, what I need is to add information to the step that asks for the persons shipping information but not the shipping rate since that will be sent from our service. Do I need to create a custom CheckoutPane and, if so, how do I make sure that information is saved to the customer's record.

Comment: `how do I make sure that information is saved to the customer's record` that should get automatically saved to the "address book", so next time they checkout its pre-filled.

Comment: Thats if I create my own shipping and billing address CheckoutPane?

Comment: Not sure with custom programmatically created checkout flow, but that's the behavior with the default flow. But... I would expect it to work the same with custom.

Comment: If you're talking about just the pane, so creating a custom shipping pane, then you should extend the [ShippingInformation](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/commerce_shipping/-/blob/8.x-2.x/src/Plugin/Commerce/CheckoutPane/ShippingInformation.php) class

Comment: Thanks! I guess what i need to accomplish for our flow is the person clicks 'Check out' and gets taken to a page that asks for shipping address and billing address (if not the same), then they are taken to a page that shows the available shipping rates returned by our internal service, then that shipping price needs to be added to the total as they go to a review page which then takes them offsite for the payment and then returned